# Regex to match an identifier and rejecting those containing invalid character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am defining a regex to match my defined identifiers - an identifier has to start with a letter followed by any number of letters, numbers, and underscores.

I have my current regex `r'[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*'` and it works great except for cases like this: if I send in: `testid@entifier_`, it returns a match for `testid` and `entifier_`. I want it to completely reject the identifier. Not match parts of it.

It just ends up splitting them.

What can I do without using a complex look-ahead for legal chars?

Input is simply:

```
arg = sys.argv[1]
file = open(arg)
inLines = file.read()
file.close()
tokens = lexer(inLines, tokenFormats)
```

A sample of my defined regex's are like this:

```
tokenFormats = [
    (r'[\s\n\t]+', None), #Whitespace
    (r'\/\*(\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\/', None), #Comment
    (r'\(', LParent),
    (r'\)', RParent),
    (r'\[', LBracket),
    (r'\]', RBracket),
    (r'\{', LBrace),
    (r'\}', RBrace),
    (r'\,', CommaT),
    (r'(?<="{1}).*?(?=")', STRLITERAL),
    (r'\"', QuoteT),
    (r'\.', PeriodT),
    (r'\-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+', ValueR),
    (r'\+', AddT),
    (r'-', AddT),
    (r'\|\|', AddT),
    (r';', Semicolon),
```

My matching loop is like this:

```
def lexer(input, tokenFormats):
    pos = 0
    tokens = []
    while pos < len(input):
        match = None
        for tokenFormat in tokenFormats:
            pattern, tag = tokenFormat
            regex = re.compile(pattern)
            match = regex.match(input,pos) #Essentially Build Lexeme
            if match:
                lexeme = match.group(0)
                if tag:
                    if tag == Identifier and len(str(lexeme)) > 27: #rough fix to check length. Very hacky
                        sys.stderr.write('Illegal length for identifier: %s\n' % lexeme)
                        break;
                    attr = checkForAttribute(lexeme,tag)
                    token = (lexeme,tag,attr)
                    tokens.append(token)
                    break
                else:
                    break
        if not match:
            sys.stderr.write('Illegal or unknown character: %s\n' % input[pos])
            pos = pos + 1
        else:
            pos = match.end(0)
    return tokens
```

Comment: Tangential, but C identifiers are allowed to start with `_` as well.

Comment: Ahh my mistake. In my lexer I am not supposed to accept them. I will edit.

Comment: It's impossible to say what the problem is unless you show how you apply the regex.

Comment: I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try anchoring your expression:

```
r'^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$'
```

This requires that the entire identifier matches the expression, not just part of it because you are anchoring the expression to the beginning and end of the string. This prevents part of the string from matching.

Comment: I entered that and now I am not matching anything? Wondering if this is an issue from how I am feeding my lexer the input file. I am feeding in the entire stream of characters in the file and iterating through that stream and my regex's to match tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If the @ symbol is your only concern, try this `r'[a-zA-Z]@?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'`.

Comment: what will happen if he has something like: `testid2@entifier_`?

Comment: I apologize, I want it to reject the entire "identifier" not match parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the `@` as well you could use the following regex:

```
r'[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*@?[A-Za-z0-9_]*'
```

**tested:** https://regex101.com/r/vlt8qo/3/

however following the description of your problem:

> I am defining a regex to match my defined identifiers - an identifier has to start with a letter followed by any number of letters, numbers, and underscores.

it looks like that there is some incoherence since `@` are not defined as part of your identifiers...

Following your edit in the post:

I have adapted my regex to ->

```
r'(?<=[\(\)\]\[\-=\+\s\n\t,;\|\.\"])[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?=[\(\)\]\[\-=\+\s\n\t,;\|\.\"])|^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?=[\(\)\]\[\-=\+\s\n\t,;\|\.\"])'
```

and tested it on several patterns @

https://regex101.com/r/vlt8qo/5/

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit to this. I am just wanting it to completely reject the potential identifier. Right now it is matching parts of it.

Comment: I ran it and now it rejects every character of the line. I'm thinking I am having issues with how my code iterates through my file that I am checking. The above code should shed some light. I am just trying to find a fix without having to completely rewrite everything.